# SQL: aggregate & transpose rows to columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to transpose the data from the first table to the second.

original data (number of cars and states are limited):

```
+----+----------+-------+--------+
| id | car      | state | tstamp |
+----+----------+-------+--------+
| 01 | toyota   |   new | 1900   |
| 02 | toyota   |   old | 1950   |
| 03 | toyota   | scrap | 1980   |
| 04 | mercedes |   new | 1990   |
| 05 | mercedes |   old | 2010   |
| 06 | tesla    |   new | 2013   |
+-----+---------------+----------+
```

query result:

```
+----------+------+------+-------+
| car      | new  | old  | scrap |
+----------+------+------+-------+
| toyota   | 1900 | 1950 | 1980  |
| mercedes | 1990 | 2010 | null  |
| tesla    | 2013 | null | null  |
+----------+------+------+-------+
```

My SQL Skills are somewhat rusty therefore I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work, depending on how your data is organised:

```
SELECT
    car,
    MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'new' THEN tstamp END) AS new,
    MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'old' THEN tstamp END) AS old,
    MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'scrap' THEN tstamp END) AS scrap
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    car;
```

Comment: +1 although you should note, that this kind of transformation should be done on application level, not database level. A database is there to get and store the data, not to make it look pretty.

Comment: thank you - I need it in this format as a subselect so I can join it 1:1 with some other tables for a view but I agree with your sentiment